# Firebase showing invalid credentials for linkedin login using next js

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, linkedin-api

```
const onClickLinkedinHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log(auth);
    
    try {
      if (linkedinUser)
        throw new Error(
            'You cannot authorization if you already have an account'
        );
        
      setIsLoadingLinkedinButton(true);
      console.log('called');
      const res = await signUpOrSignInWithLinkedin();
      console.log('res', res);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      
      if (error.code === 'auth/popup-closed-by-user') return;
      toast.error(error.message, {
        position: 'bottom-right',
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
      });
    } finally {
      setIsLoadingLinkedinButton(false);
    }
    }, [linkedinUser, signUpOrSignInWithLinkedin]);\\\
```

It is giving error when I tries to login with linkedin using firebase

Comment: Can you provide the specific error that you receive?

Comment: I am getting invalid/auth-credtinals while calling signUpOrSignInWithLinkedin function